# Using only one credential to do load testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Im currently new to end to end testing and planning to do load testing for a website I am currently working on. Im currently looking into jmeter and studying how to use it. My question is, would it make sense to only use one credential for the test? So basically I will be using my credentials then would throwing same HTTP requests multiple times to the server to simulate several users logging in and using the website.

Also if there are other ways to do load testing without using more than one credentials would be helpful!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use cases and your site implementation, possible problems could be:

1. The site may not allow multiple logins under the same credentials like subsequent login will "throw out" the previously logged in user(s)
2. Depending on how [session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session) is being established/maintained you may receive the same [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for the same login
3. Most probably you will be able to implement browsing, but [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations can be a big question mark

From JMeter's perspective it is not a problem to use only one account, any constraints will be on the system under test side.

Ideally you should treat each JMeter thread (virtual user) as the real user and it worth creating that many users as you plan to simulate and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to parameterize your JMeter test so each virtual user could have its own credentials

Comment: thanks for the information, this helped a lot in understanding load testing :) especially on testing websites